# Photo Upload On Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, window

I want to Upload Photo to Facebook Page using HttpWebRequest

and I don't want to use Facebook Graph API ..

via live http header i get the url and data which is need to be posted

user=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&_a=1&_*dyn=XXXXXXXXXXXX&*_req=s&fb_dtsg=AQAszPoc&ttstamp=26581651151228011199&__rev=1141676">https://upload.facebook.com/ajax/composerx/attachment/media/saveunpublished?target_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX1&_*user=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&*_a=1&_*dyn=XXXXXXXXXXXX&*_req=s&fb_dtsg=AQAszPoc&ttstamp=26581651151228011199&__rev=1141676

DATA which will be used for sending with url

```
  -----------------------------3300296215819
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fb_dtsg"

AQAszPoc
-----------------------------3300296215819
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"

8
-----------------------------3300296215819
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_id"

xxxxxxxxxxx
-----------------------------3300296215819
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grid_id"

u_6_0
-----------------------------3300296215819
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qn"

a9f0f5a0f2104b0ef0656f692cda9893
-----------------------------3300296215819
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="0"; filename="1794679_698919370150942_1311355907_n.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

YOUR DATA OR IMAGE

-----------------------------85332783618735
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_id"

1025
-----------------------------85332783618735--
```

I m not sure how to get this value 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qn"

```
a9f0f5a0f2104b0ef0656f692cda9893
```

can someone helpe me out 
everytime when i tried to upload i got error

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357032,"errorSummary":"Sorry, we got confused","errorDescription":"Please try refreshing the page or closing and re-opening your browser window.","payload":null,"bootloadable":{},"ixData":[]}
```

---

reason why i don't want to use FaceBook Graph API is that whenever we post/upload it display message " 33 minutes ago **via Graph API Explore**"

please help me out

Thanks